# Import data from txt file into C program

Tags: c, file-io

I need to import some data from a `data.txt` file in a C program. My data source is like this:

```
A ABC001 B
A ABC002 B
A ABC003 C
B ABC004 C
B ABC005 E
C ABC006 B
D ABC007 A
D ABC008 B
E ABC009 D
```

I have defined a new data type to hold all the information:

```
typedef struct node {
    char street_name;
    char number_plate[7];
    char destination;
} Car;
```

Here it is my attempt to import the data from the file above into an array:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int i = 0;
    Car carinfo[9];

    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (EOF != fscanf(file, "%c %6s %c", &carinfo[i].street_name,
                                            &carinfo[i].number_plate, 
                                            &carinfo[i].destination))
    {
        printf("Loop #%d\n", i+1);
        i++;
    }



    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("Street Name: %c, Number Plate: %s, Destination: %c\n", carinfo[i].street_name, 
                                                                       carinfo[i].number_plate, 
                                                                       carinfo[i].destination);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The `while` loop is being executed for 10 times and then makes the program crash, because apparently it disregards the `EOS` that should prevent another iteration.

What is that I am doing wrong here? Can anyone please help me figure out?

Comment: Please always include the proper headers in your examples.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Does it crash with segmentation fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change

```
while (EOF != fscanf(file, "%c %6s %c", &carinfo[i].street_name,
```

to

```
while (3 == fscanf(file, " %c %6s %c", &carinfo[i].street_name,
```

and try again.

Every line on your input file has a newline, and it should be ignored, the space before the first `%c` will do that.

Comment: It works!! Thank you. Could you explain what was wrong?

Comment: @haunted85 Are you sure you copy and paste my code?

Comment: I didn't notice the extra space... fixed and it works beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Beware though: If you don't have exactly 9 inputs, your program will still crash. If more, in scanning, if less, in printing.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, that is another problem needs to be fixed. If you does not know the number of lines in advance, using `realloc()` seems the only way to handle this.

Comment: @haunted85 Explanation added to my answer.